# how to maintain session in android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-networking, android-websettings

I am new to android .In my application i need to maintain a session when first connection of web service(i need to implement java server web service  urls when i call the first url i got response.  after that second url  call it gives the false response .thing is i need to call the url with in the same session as i called my first url)  .I found different answers but i don't under stand those.what i am expecting is how to get the session id when my first call and how can i keep those in further activities. please share sample code or related docs or relate answers.I hope you understand my intention .

Comment: not quite sure i fully understand your problem, you want to keep users session id throughout your application?

Comment: thanks for u r response .you got my point.i need some sample snippets of code please help me.

Answer (score 0):

to get cookies or session from the server if using http client use this:

```
     List<Cookie> cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore().getCookies();

             if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("TAG","no cookies received");
             } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {

                    if(cookies.get(i).getName().contentEquals("ASP.NET_SessionId")) {
                     asp = cookies.get(i).getValue();
                   }
                }
                Log.e("this is the cookiee", asp);
                }
```

Comment: While in general this answer is correct, it does assume you are using ASP.NET on the server side. If your server uses another framework (or you maintain your own session), you should figure out the exact cookie the session is stored.

Comment: yap it will depend on the session name like PHPSESSID or whatever the server sets for the session name